# Change drop-shadow with Javascript without jQuery

Tags: javascript, css, drop-shadow

I want to add the style `-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222);` in JavaScript without jQuery.

I want create a shadow for png transparent image duration with CSS transform.

This code is not working correctly:

```js
var scscsc = document.getElementById('scscsc');
scscsc.setAttribute("style", "-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222);");
scscsc.style.transform = "rotate(216deg)";
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://sirati.info/tmp/ss.png" id="scscsc">
```

Comment: Check out my answer, it should work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uzbekjon's answer will only work if that is the only CSS property you are using. It's preferable to set inline CSS using the `style` property of the element like so:

```
var elt = document.getElementById("#your-element-id");

elt.style.setProperty("-webkit-filter", "drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222)");
```

Edit: here is a working JSfiddle demonstrating this works

https://jsfiddle.net/w4n024b4/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var elt = document.getElementById("#your-element-id");

elt.setAttribute("style", "-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222);");
```

Comment: not worked currently when i use elt.style.transform for rotate this image with shadow

Comment: @Uzbekjon Still, you should avoid overriding the `style` attribute _in general_.

Comment: my question modified.

Comment: I understand that and agree. I'm saying we don't know about any other calls to elt.style...